# The Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand why the following question is correct. Regarding to the MVT.

Given: Find a number c satisfying the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem

1. $f(x)= x^{1/3}$, on $[-1,2]$
2. $f(x)= x^{1/3}$, on $[0,2]$

For 1) I found that $f(x)$ is continuous and but not differentiable at $x=0$. For 2) I found that $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on $[0,2]$

$$
f'(x)= 1/3 \, x^{-2/3}
$$

$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = 
\frac{f(2)-f(-1)}{2+1} = 
\frac{2^{1/3} + 1}{3} = 0.7533070166
$$
I found $C= 0.29$

For 2) I found $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on interval $[0,2]$.

$$
f'(x)= 1/3 \, x^{-2/3}
$$

$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}= 
\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}= 
0.6299605249
$$
I found $c= 0.3849001795$

What i don't understand is the differentiability. Especially for 1) it's not differentiable at $x=0$ but for 2) it's differentiable.

The mean value theorem states that 1) continuous on $[a,b]$ 2) differntiable on $(a,b)$ and 3) for at least one value $c$ in $(a,b)$ s.t. 
$$
f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} .
$$

For 1) function is continuous. there is at least one value $c$ in $[-1,2]$. Here is what I dont understand, function is NOT differentiable on $(-1,2)$. why? for 2) it's differentiable on $(0,2)$. my professor said that's bc it's not differentiable at $x=0$ for 1).

I am confused as to know how we can know when function is not differentiable at $x=0$? Do i just plug $x=0$ into the function? Do we graph first and then see if the graph displays cups or corner?  like for 1) and 2) i was able to know that function is continuous and there is at least one value $C$ in $(a,b)$  s.t. $f'(c)= f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)$.  I found the value of $C$ for both 1) and 2). I was able to take derivative of $f(x)$. for 1) it's not differentiable but for 2) it's differentiable. I thought it was differentiable for both since i was able to take derivative of the function..

help please..It bothers me that i do not understand clearly what she meant by not differentiable at $x=0$. ugh.

Comment: Both functions are not differentiable in $x=0$

Comment: then 1) nd 2) fail to meet the MVT, right? but how come 2) is differentiable? but not differentiable for 1)

Comment: Just for clearification: The MVT states that **IF** some conditions are fulfilled, **then** there is a point $c$ inside the domain such that the intermediate slope is attained. That is all. You still may find a point $c$ such that the intermediate slope is attained even though the functions is not differentiable (inside its domain). However, **if** there is no such point $c$ find such a point, **then** $f$ is not differentiable everywhere inside its domain. ($(A\Rightarrow B=\Longleftrightarrow (\lnot B \Rightarrow \lnot A)$

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is **not** differentiable in $x=0$. However, the mean value theorem can be applied to your second case since $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ **and** differentiable on $(0,2)$. Check precisely the requirements of the MVT.

The differentiability on $(0,2)$ follows since the formula by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner in the other answer holds.

Differentiabily is defined pointwise. You have to check every point insinde the domain of the function if the difference quotients converge. This does not happen in $x=0$ as we infer from the following argument. If $f$ was differentiable in $x=0$ then the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$ must exists. Here $h$ is in $[-1,2]\setminus\{0\}$  or in $(0,2]$.

However, we find $$\frac{f(h)}{h}=\frac{1}{h^{2/3}}\xrightarrow{h\to 0}\infty.$$ Thus the difference quotient does not converge.

Comment: thats my question. HOW?

Comment: it seems like it has to do with the interval

Comment: If the interval was let's say [-5,5] then f(x) is still not differentiable bc x=0 correct?

Comment: what does bc mean?

Comment: because** sorry for misleading

Comment: For the mean value to be applicable, the function in question only has to be differentiable **on the interior** of the interval on which it is defined (but continuous on the whole interval). Hence, $f$ is not differentiable in $0$ in **both** cases, but in the second it does not matter, because $0$ is not in the **interior** of $[0,2]$.

Comment: thnanks for clarity

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}$ is for $x=0$ not defined.

Comment: Even though your function is not defined in zero, this does not imply that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: hello, it is the first derivative you can also consider $\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\frac{h^{1/3}}{h}=\frac{1}{h^{2/3}}$